# Problem with mini sliding gate

Tags: circuit-design, motor, relay

I am learning about relays and to practice what I have learned I have decided to make a small electric gate using the following method. I am making a circuit to control the opening and closing of the gate with three push buttons and two limit switches. Pushbutton S1 opens the gate, S2 closes it, S3 is an emergency stop pushbutton, FCI1 is the left limit switch and FCD1 is the right limit switch. Everything works fine, but there is a problem, if the motor is turning in one direction and I press the push button to turn the motor in the other direction, the motor stops (it should keep turning until it reaches the limit switch or S3 is pressed). How can I do so that when it turns in one direction, no matter if it is given the order to turn in the other direction, it keeps turning until it reaches the limit switch or when S3 is pressed (as far as possible without using another relay)?

Circuit:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. The buttons are powered only if the opposing relay is not latched.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought of that, it works. Did you design it in livewire too? How did you do to invert the relay contact positions? Thanks

Comment: I used MS Paint! Select a region, flip it and drag to new location. A bit of fill and patch up the lines. (A bit painful but it made it easy for you to relate to.)

Answer (score 1):

Pressing S1 latches RL1 putting 5V on the motor'a left terminal. Pressing S2 latches RL2 placing 5V on the right motor terminal without releasing latches RL1. The motor now has 5V one each terminal and so will stop.

Correction:
@Transistor pointed out a misunderstanding. I leave this answer as a solution for a reversing function without having to emergency stop.

An alternative  solution is to have S2/S1 release RL1/S2 when pressed thus providing a reversing function.

Comment: One of us has misunderstood the question. I think the OP wants to complete the current motion once started.

Comment: @Transistor: You're right I did misunderstand. I will leave my answer as a way to include a revering mechanism.